# Lambda matches signature of a FunctionalInterface, yet "does not". How do you explain that the argument is passed at all?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, invokedynamic

I am working on [this project](https://github.com/fge/throwing-lambdas) currently. It works surprisingly well.

Yet, after re-reading the README again, I started to wonder about how to document something that is bugging me...

To quote the example, and forgetting for a moment that exceptions can be thrown, it reads:

```
Files.list(somePath).map(Path::toRealPath).forEach(System.out::println)
```

OK. Now, the method of `Path` involved is [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-). Of course, we do not pass any `LinkOption`.

Again: let's forget for a moment that it throws any exception.

Stream's `.map()` takes a `Function` as an argument. This interface, for `Function<T, R>`, is defined as:

```
R apply(T t);
```

But the method I am using accepts no arguments. At a first glance, it does not seem to match a `Function`, right? Except that...

It can be written as:

```
path -> path.toRealPath()
```

It therefore looks like the mechanism used is somewhat able to invoke a method on the "stream object" if the method reference has no argument, or something like that...

I'd like to document this accordingly, and I am missing something here.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-static methods have the receiver (`this`) object as an implicit first argument. Therefore, `Class::nonStaticMethod` has one more argument than you might expect.

Java Language Specification Section 15.13.1, [Compile-Time Declaration of a Method Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1):

> - Second, given a targeted function type with *n* parameters, a set of potentially applicable methods is identified:
>
>   - If the method reference expression has the form *ReferenceType* `::` *[TypeArguments] Identifier*, the potentially applicable methods are the member methods of the type to search that have an appropriate name (given by *Identifier*), accessibility, arity (*n* or *n-1*), and type argument arity (derived from *[TypeArguments]*), as specified in §15.12.2.1.
>
>     *Two different arities, n and n-1, are considered, to account for the possibility that this form refers to either a `static` method or an instance method.*

Comment: OK, that would explain everything indeed! Hrm... Might I bugger you and ask that you edit your post with some relevant links as a Christmas present? ;)

Comment: No, you can't bugger (sodomise) me, but you can bug me, sure. :-)

Comment: OK, so, as a quick rundown: in the example, `ReferenceType` is `Path`; accessibility OK; name does not matter (right?); arity OK (1 or 0, here 0); and since the method reference is an instance method, the expected arity is 0, and as it happens, it returns `ReferenceType`. Am I on the right track?

Comment: The name check is to find a method named `toRealPath`, in this case. A method reference of `Path::methodThatDoesNotExist` would not be valid, for example.

Comment: Ah; I have somewhat overlooked the "compile" in "compile time declaration of a method reference". So, do I take it to mean that it is the role of the compiler to generate a call site with `this` (as in, the current element of the stream) as the first argument?

Comment: Yes, that is what happens.

Comment: That makes things clear now! Thanks a lot! Sorry for that unfortunate tongue slip and have a flowing end of a year ;)